# How do I pass a return value to another function and assign the return value to a variable within that function?

Tags: c++, function, class

My program consist of 3 files. The clockType.h - the class function prototypes, clockTypeImp.cpp - definitions of functions, and the testing program testClockClass.cpp.

I am trying to pass the return value of the first function to the next function in the code below. I think I am supposed to pass it as a reference perimeter, or a pointer*.

You can see my failed attempt at assigning the return value to the variable `diffSec`.

(What I am trying to do is convert the difference in seconds between two clocks and out put that difference as `HH:MM:SS`).

Part of my clockTypeImp.cpp implementation file:

```
int clockType::clockDiffseconds(clockType otherClock) {
    int elapsedSec;
    return (abs(elapsedTimeSeconds() - otherClock.elapsedTimeSeconds()));
}

void clockType::secondsToHHMMSS() {
    int diffSec = clockType::clockDiffseconds(clockType otherClock);
    int diffHours = diffSec/3600;
    int diffMinutes = (diffSec/60)%60;
    int diffSeconds = diffSec%60;
    cout << "Converted to HH:MM:SS: " << diffHours << ":" << diffMinutes << ":" << diffSeconds;
}
```

Part of my clockType.h file where clockType is coming from:

```
class clockType {
     public:
     void remainingTimeSeconds(int& totalEndSec);     // Function to convert clock to time remaining in seconds.
     int clockDiffseconds(clockType otherClock); // Function for finding difference in time between clocks.
     void secondsToHHMMSS();    // Function for converting seconds to HH:MM:SS.
     bool equalTime(const clockType& otherClock) const;     // Function to compair the two times.
     private:
     int hr;     // Variable to store the hours.
     int min;    // Variable to store the minutes.
     int sec;    // Variable to store the seconds.
};
```

Here is part of my testing program.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "clockType.h"

using namespace std;

int main() {
        clockType myClock;
        clockType yourClock;

        int hours;
        int minutes;
        int seconds;
        int elapsedSec;
        int totalEndSec;

        cout << endl << "myClock Time is not set:\n";
        myClock.printTime();

        cout << endl << "myClock Time is set:\n";
        myClock.setTime(9, 3, 30);
        myClock.printTime();
        cout << endl;

        cout << endl << "yourClock Time is not set:\n";
        yourClock.printTime();

        cout << endl << "yourClock Time is set:\n";
        yourClock.setTime(5, 45, 16);
        yourClock.printTime();
        cout << endl << endl;

        if (myClock.equalTime(yourClock)) {
                cout << "Both times are equal." << endl;
        } else {
                cout << "The two times are not equal." << endl;
        }

        cout << endl << "Set the time for myClock\nEnter the hours, minutes, and seconds:\n";

     yourClock.remainingTimeSeconds(totalEndSec);
     cout << "\x1B[32m-->\033[0m" << " The total remaining seconds of \x1B[32myourClock\033[0m is: " << totalEndSec << endl;

     myClock.remainingTimeSeconds(totalEndSec);
     cout << "\x1B[33m-->\033[0m" << " The total remaining seconds of \x1B[33mmyClock\033[0m is: " << totalEndSec << endl;
        
     cout << endl;
        
     cout << "\x1B[34m-->\033[0m" << " The difference in seconds between the \x1B[34mtwo clocks\033[0m is: " << myClock.clockDiffseconds(yourClock) << endl;
```

Let me know if you need to see the full code of the file(s).

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide a [mcve]. There are syntax mistakes in your `secondsToHHMMSS()`, but the correct way to fix them depends on how you are trying to use `secondsToHHMMSS()` in the rest of your code. How is `clockType` declared? How is `secondsToHHMMSS()` being called? Where is `otherClock` coming from?

Comment: I have edited and added information to my post.

Comment: Added information, yes, but not a [mre] (a MRE). What you want to give is the smallest possible complete program that reproduces the error you are seeing. We then drop your code into our tools and kick it around for a while until we find the problem. Thing is, making the MRE usually ends early because you spot and fix the bug yourself while trimming off the program's fat.

Comment: @BlueWolf You claim to be having trouble implementing `secondsToHHMMSS()`, but nothing in your `main()` example is actually trying to call `secondsToHHMMSS()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`clockDiffseconds()` is a non-`static` method that acts on `this`, calculating the difference in seconds between `this` and another clock `otherClock`. That is fine.

But `secondsToHHMMSS()` has no concept of `otherClock`.  It is also a non-`static` method that acts only on `this`.  So, for `secondsToHHMMSS()` to be meaningful, you have a few choices:

- re-think what `secondsToHHMMSS()` actually means to you.  The way you have written it, it should just print the current seconds of `this` as-is. In which case, use the value returned by `clockDiffseconds()` to constructs a new `clockType` object whose `elapsedTimeSeconds()` returns just that value, and then call `secondsToHHMMSS()` on that new `clockType` object, eg:

  ```
  class clockType {
  public:
      ...
      clockType clockDiff(clockType otherClock) const;
      void secondsToHHMMSS() const;
      ...
  };
  ```

  ```
  clockType clockType::clockDiff(clockType otherClock) const {
      int elaspedSec = abs(elapsedTimeSeconds() - otherClock.elapsedTimeSeconds());
      return clockType(elaspedSec);
      // add a constructor to clockType that stores elaspedSec in such
      // a way that its elapsedTimeSeconds() can then return it...
  }

  void clockType::secondsToHHMMSS() const {
      int elapsedSec = elapsedTimeSeconds();
      int hours = elapsedSec/3600;
      int minutes = (elapsedSec/60)%60;
      int seconds = elapsedSec%60;
      cout << "Converted to HH:MM:SS: " << hours << ":" << minutes << ":" << seconds;
  }
  ```

  ```
  clockType myClock, yourClock, elapsed;
  ...
  elapsed = myClock.clockDiff(yourClock);
  elapsed.secondsToHHMMSS();
  ...
  ```
- Otherwise, if you really want `secondsToHHMMSS()` to express the difference in seconds between two clocks, then you will have to pass in the `otherClock` as a parameter to `secondsToHHMMSS()`, just like you already do with `clockDiffseconds()`, eg:

  ```
  class clockType {
  public:
      ...
      int clockDiffseconds(clockType otherClock) const;
      void secondsToHHMMSS(clockType otherClock) const;
      ...
  };
  ```

  ```
  int clockType::clockDiffseconds(clockType otherClock) const {
      return abs(elapsedTimeSeconds() - otherClock.elapsedTimeSeconds());
  }

  void clockType::secondsToHHMMSS(clockType otherClock) const {
      int diffSec = clockDiffseconds(otherClock);
      int diffHours = diffSec/3600;
      int diffMinutes = (diffSec/60)%60;
      int diffSeconds = diffSec%60;
      cout << "Converted to HH:MM:SS: " << diffHours << ":" << diffMinutes << ":" << diffSeconds;
  }
  ```

  ```
  clockType myClock, yourClock;
  ...
  myClock.secondsToHHMMSS(yourClock);
  ...
  ```
- Otherwise, consider changing `secondsToHHMMSS()` to be a `static` method instead, and then pass in the desired seconds as a parameter, such as from an earlier call to `clockDiffseconds()`, eg:

  ```
  class clockType {
  public:
      ...
      static void secondsToHHMMSS(int seconds);
      ...
  };
  ```

  ```
  void clockType::secondsToHHMMSS(int seconds) const {
      int hours = seconds/3600;
      int minutes = (seconds/60)%60;
      seconds = seconds%60;
      cout << "Converted to HH:MM:SS: " << hours << ":" << minutes << ":" << seconds;
  }
  ```

  ```
  clockType myClock, yourClock;
  ...
  int diffSec = myClock.clockDiffseconds(yourClock);
  clockType::secondsToHHMMSS(diffSec);
  ...
  ```